# Video autoplay in browsers

Tags: javascript, autoplay

I am aware that browsers now try to prevent autoplay.  We have an educational site that plays a number of videos in a row.  When each video loads, we want to it to play without being muted.  The videos may be as short as a minute or minute and a half, and asking a user to unmute for every video would be a bad experience.  Is there any way around this issue? For example can we allow them to confirm a popup at the beginning of the experience, and not have to do it after that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html5 video autoplay feature not working without muted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287175/html5-video-autoplay-feature-not-working-without-muted)

Comment: Yes, dt, something like that would work, though probably only video by video.

Comment: So, if a lesson is 5 videos, can it happen once per lesson, or are you saying once per video, and thus five times per lesson?